# elasticsearch aggregation to sort by ratio of aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a scenario in analytics where I want to calculate **least performing 20 outlets** out of 1000+ outlets where `performance = transactionCount/ VisitCount` per month at an outlet.

Mappings are,

```
{
 "CustomerVisit": {
   "properties": {
     "outlet": {
       "type": "string",
       "index": "not_analyzed"
     },
     "customerName": {
       "type": "string",
       "index": "not_analyzed"
     },
     "visitMonth": {
       "type": "Date"
     },
    "visit": {
       "type": "nested",
       "properties": {
         "visitStatus": {
           "type": "long"
         },
         "transactionStatus": {
           "type": "long"
         },
         "remarks": {
           "type": "string",
           "index": "not_analyzed"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Now, What I want is aggregate in such a way that gives me 20 outlets out of 1000+ sorted by ratio of **aggregation of visitStatus** to **aggregation of transactionStatus**.

I couldn't find a way to solve it using `aggs`, I don't know if script could be implemented here. The rough solution I was about to implement was

1. aggregate by least transactionCount, get 20 buckets(with outlet
   names/counts) [one query executed]
2. aggregate by visitCount for above 20 outlets [another query]
3. divide count1 by count2 to get ratio

But this would never give me right result, because I'm sorting by least transactions not ratio of transactions/visits.